# How can I get a bullet to seek targets?

Tags: rotation, godot, godot4

I'm  trying to make a rocket that seeks out targets and turns to them, but the rotation seems to not work.
My code is as follows:

```
var bullet_type = "Normal"
var seeking
var dead
var speed

func _process(delta):
    if not dead:
        position += Vector2(sin(rotation) * speed * delta, cos(rotation) * -speed * delta)
    if bullet_type == "Rocket" and speed < initial_speed * 5:
        speed += 30 * delta

    if bullet_type == "Rocket" and seeking and not dead:
        if target and is_instance_valid(target):
            var target_rot = atan2(target.global_position.y - global_position.y, target.global_position.x - global_position.x)
            global_rotation = target_rot
        elif not is_instance_valid(target) or not target:
            for asteroid in get_parent().get_node("Asteroids").get_children():
                if not target:
                    target = asteroid
                elif dist(position, asteroid.position) < dist(position, target.position):
                    target = asteroid
```

However, the rockets did not change course and simply moved in a straight line.

I confirmed that the lines of code were actually being executed by adding a `print(global_rotation)` after the line `global_rotation = target_rot` and it did print out the rotation in radians, but the rotation wasn't changing.

I changed the line `global_rotation = target_rot` to `global_rotation += 0.1` and the rotation still did not change whatsoever. This should have resulted in the rocket curving or at least changing directions, but it just moved in a straight line.

What's more is that the rockets do actually accelerate, meaning that changing the speed did work, but not the rotation.
I even tried adding a `print(global_rotation)` before `global_rotation += 0.1`, but it showed no difference.

Lastly, I printed the `target_rot` variable, and it seemed to make geometric sense.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a function called "look_at" maybe take a look at this.
other than that in the movement you used "rotation" but than you used global_rotation maybe they got confused?